# Endnote not displayed

Tags: endnotes

As per the publisher rules, the endnotes section should come before the appendix section. 
Am using one `\endnote` in appendix section, How I get the last endnote output, it has not appeared in the  `endnote` section.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\title{This is endnote testing}

\author{Note}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 1st endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 2nd endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 3rd endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 4th endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 5th endnote}

\theendnotes

\appendix
\section{Section}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 6th endnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try with the newer version, which is released just two days before? But I'm not sure...

Comment: How's the reader supposed to know that the sixth endnote appears later than the list of endnotes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the text before the endnote file is closed, and just make the mark later.

I left in the word spaces before all the marks but they look a bit odd to me, I would expect `fooo\endnote{...}` not `foo \endnote{....}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\title{This is endnote testing}

\author{Note}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 1st endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 2nd endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 3rd endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 4th endnote}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnote{This is 5th endnote}

\endnotetext[6]{This is 6th endnote}
\theendnotes

\appendix
\section{Section}

This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. \endnotemark[6]

\end{document}
```